# How to get the log loss?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, metrics

I am playing with the Leaf Classification data set and  I am struggling to compute the log loss of my model after testing it. After importing it from the metrics class here I do:

```
 # fitting the knn with train-test split 
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
 
 # Optimisation via gridSearch
 knn=KNeighborsClassifier()
 params={'n_neighbors': range(1,40), 'weights':['uniform', 'distance'], 'metric':['minkowski','euclidean'],'algorithm': ['auto','ball_tree','kd_tree', 'brute']}
 k_grd=GridSearchCV(estimator=knn,param_grid=params,cv=5)
 k_grd.fit(X_train,y_train)
 
 # testing 
 yk_grd=k_grd.predict(X_test)

 # calculating the logloss 
 print (log_loss(y_test, yk_grd))
```

However, my last line is resulting in the following error:

```
 y_true and y_pred contain different number of classes 93, 2. Please provide the true labels explicitly through the labels argument. Classes found in y_true.
```

But the when I run the following:

```
X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape, yk_grd.shape
# results
((742, 192), (248, 192), (742,), (248,), (248,))
```

what am i missing really?

Comment: What happens changing last line this way: `print (log_loss(y_test, k_grd.predict_proba(X_test)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`sklearn.metrics.log_loss` documentantion](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html):

> y_pred : array-like of float, shape = (n_samples, n_classes) or
>   (n_samples,)
>
> Predicted probabilities, as returned by a classifier’s predict_proba method.

Then, to get `log loss`:

```
yk_grd_probs = k_grd.predict_proba(X_test)
print(log_loss(y_test, yk_grd_probs))
```

---

If you still get an error, it means that a specific class is missing in `y_test`.

Use:

`print(log_loss(y_test, yk_grd_probs, labels=all_classes))`

where `all_classes` is a list containing all the classes in your dataset.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue  when doing that. I will investigate further. This is also what I can see in the documentation. I have tried that several times. that's why I printed the shape of all the data I have and still tells me a problem with the number of classes.

Comment: @Camue check my further note.

Comment: Thank you. Yes you are right. Predic_proba mode allows you compare the proba with real label and compute the log_loss further.